# refresh the map Ol3 (Openlayers3)

Tags: openlayers

I'm  using ol3 in a  mobile  hybrid application using sencha touch2  , so I start by drawing a polygon inside a map , after validating this drawing I  redirect the user to an other form in order to fill the alphanumeric  informations of that polygon , My problem is when I want to get back  to  my map  the layers disappear and the only way to make them get back is to change the device Orientation.  so I'm looking for code snippet that can reload (refresh) my layers or the whole map

I tried
    `map.dispatchChangeEvent();`

or `vectorSource.dispatchChangeEvent();`

but nothing works for me

---

I find the solution is to update the map size  like  this : map.updateSize();

I

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:**

To solve the issue just use `map.updateSize();`.

**Initial answer**

Firstly, I recommended unsuccessfully, to try `map.render()` or `map.renderSync()`

The first one `map.render()` make (citing [official doc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.Map.html?unstable=true#render))

> Requests a render frame; rendering will effectively occur at the next
>   browser animation frame.

The second one do

> Requests an immediate render in a synchronous manner.

Comment: Thanks @b-eyes and @ThomasG77, but why not posting the `map.updateSize();` as an answer? That would help people to find a solution to the problem (there seem to be several question on the same topic still unanswered).

Comment: I've edited my answer